# Correct way to pass a path as an argument for a GET request

Tags: c#, api, parameter-passing

I have an API endpoint that looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MyApiMethod(string path)
{
    // do stuff with path

    return Ok();
}
```

Obviously I can't just pass the path along otherwise my call will 404. I thought base64 encoding it would be correct, but apparently base64 encoding leads to symbols such as '+', '/', and '='...which will also cause random errors in hitting the endpoint. How am I supposed to pass a path as an argument to an API GET request?

Answer (score 0):

**path='api/yourcontroller name/your action name'**

This will be the method to pass path to api controller

Answer (score 0):

Using `string path` as an argument of a `GET` API is a bad idea. First, developers using this API should understand your implementations detailly, like "do I need to url-encode the path?" or "is the path starts with / or not?" or "what if I put the hostname in the path?". Second, you need to care about the security issues.

I'd like to use an `enum` that lists all supported actions.

```
public enum ApiAction
{
    This,
    That
}

public ActionResult MyApiMethod(ApiAction apiAction)
{
     //get the path from enum via a method or something
     var path = GetPath(apiAction);

     //do something to path
}
```

Comment: Enum is not possible, api will return stream data from file living at path. Path is dynamic so no enums

Comment: @user3689167 so you mean the developers can pass any `path` to the api?